# How to create a table and after upload data with python 2.7?

Tags: mysql, csv, mysql-python

I have a csv file, what i want to write into a mysql database. (python2.7)
In this csv file there are 6 columns, and a lot of row.
There isn't any primary key in this table, so i want to use an generated primary key (like 1,2,3,4 etc..). 
How can i change my code, to create this table and after put these cells into it.

My code looks like this :

```js
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import MySQLdb

connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='1234',
    db='database')
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """ load data local infile 'C:/Python27/output.csv' 
into table XXX
character set latin1
fields terminated by ';'
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 1 lines;
"""
cursor.execute(query)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

This is an insert into code, how can i changed it to create a table and then upload these dataes? (+ question: this is good if i use this "fields terminated by ';'" ? because there isnt any ";" sign in the csv file..)